# WiFi not working on MacBook Pro running 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless, apt, kernel, macbook

I've seen many other posts like this and found one other where the problem was resolved, but the terminal commands given were for a different pcid than mine. I ran several commands including:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

which got the response:

`linux-headers-generic` is already the newest version.

I also ran:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bmcwl-kernel-source
```

Which got the error message:

```
E: unable to locate package bmcwl-kernel-source
```

I am new to Linux, but this seems to be a pretty common issue with 12.10. My pcid is 14e4:4331

If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You typed:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bmcwl-kernel-source
```

It is not bmcwl, it is *bcmwl*:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```